# Nexus 5 > Lollipop upgrade notification lost

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, updates, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I have an LG **Nexus 5** and I am running **Android 4.4.4** on it.

I've been seeing a notification telling me there's an upgrade for my Android OS for several weeks now (Lollipop upgrade), but I've been waiting till I properly back up my phone before starting the upgrade.

When I was finally ready to run the upgrade yesterday, the notification was gone. I went to **Settings > About phone > System updates**, clicked on "**Check for update**" only to find it saying "Your system is up to date".

The "Last checked for update at" message was changed to the current time.

Rebooting the phone and trying again did not help either.

Is there anyway I can get that Lollipop update back?

Comment: Well, I would say they may have rolled the update back because of he bugs present over it ! I have been hearing that there are a number of bugs over Android Lollipop. Which I guess is the reason why the update dis-appeared. Maybe you should wait a bit more while ! And I would say that as you are running KitKat, it's way more good than Lollipop better would be not to because I have seen that people running Lollipop, wants their devices to roll back over to the KitKat.

Comment: As Peter wrote, 5.0 had many issues. AFAIK they (preparing to) rollout 5.0.1 already. So you might have been lucky to skip 5.0 – and just have to wait for the "next round".