# How to get Lollipop update for Nexus 5?

Tags: updates, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

I bought Nexus 5, it had android 4.4.2. I updated it to 4.4.3 and 4.4.4, but I am unable to update it to 5.0. It says that system is up to date and it has been this way for a few hours.
I know that Nexus 5 has 5.0.2 (I think) already. Why is my phone not finding any new updates?

Comment: Also: [Nexus 5 lollipop upgrade notification lost](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91744/nexus-5-lollipop-upgrade-notification-lost?rq=1) - TLDR; you can't force an OTA update, when google rolls out to your device you will get the update.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out OTA updates can take up to several weeks. There is a solution: you can manually install OTA updates by yourself. There are tons of guides out there.