# Nexus 5 lollipop update notification not showing up

Tags: updates, nexus-5, 5.0-lollipop

My nexus 5 was showing the lollipop update notification till mid December. Now this is not showing up. While checking for system updates it shows the current time and os is up to date.

Any one please help me out on how i can bring back that notification as 5.0.1 has been released now.

Comment: related: [Nexus 5 > Lollipop upgrade notification lost](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91744/nexus-5-lollipop-upgrade-notification-lost?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google releases their OTA updates in waves. If you have dismissed the notification (on purpose or by accident) you may not be eligible again until the next wave cycle. Many users have reported significant wait times.

If you want to update manually you can do so by flashing a [factory image](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images), although be warned, this will wipe your data.

You can also [sideload](http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/general/ref-nexus-5-stock-ota-urls-t2475327) the update files, which will keep the data intact.

Comment: By next Wave cycle you mean that i need to wait until 6.0 releases or 5.0.1(already released right, still i didn't get the update)? Now i have 4.4.4 installed. Will i get the next update unless i install 5.0?

Comment: By next wave I mean when Google decides to send the OTA notifications out again. You don't have to wait for the next android update.

Comment: The last notification i saw in my phone was of 5.0. Now 5.0.1 has been released, right? Please tell me why didn't i receive 5.0.1 notification?

Comment: @harun welcome to lollipop :)

Answer (score 0):

I received 5.0.1 OTA on my N5 2 days ago. It jumped from 4.4.4 to 5.0.1 bypassing 5.0. My N4 was upgraded to 5.0.1 in November. Just be patient, it will come.